# Debugging FuncAnimation

Tags: matplotlib, debugging, animation, spyder

Consider

```
def animate(k):
   # do stuff, update plots

anm = FuncAnimation(myFig, animate, interval=1, repeat=False)
```

Why is it not possible to debug anything inside `animate`?

I can run the same code without visualization in barebones Python and perfectly debug it, but somehow `FuncAnimation` is totally "opaque".

My IDE is `Spyder 4.0.1`

**UPDATE**

I am still struggling to debug `FuncAnimation`.
Does anyone know how to do that?
I can't see what's happening inside `animate`.

Comment: You can see the source code of `FuncAnimation` [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/_modules/matplotlib/animation.html#FuncAnimation)

Comment: @Sameeresque So what?